# Cannot upload/download files through google drive api

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload images from my app to google drive but its showing error

> Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=501 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2263 6f646522 3a343033 2c226d65 73736167 65223a22 496e7375 66666963 69656e74 20506572 6d697373 696f6e22 2c226461 7461223a 5b7b2264 6f6d6169 6e223a22 676c6f62 616c222c 22726561 736f6e22 3a22696e 73756666 69636965 6e745065 726d6973 73696f6e 73222c22 6d657373 61676522 3a22496e 73756666 69636965 6e742050 65726d69 7373696f 6e227d5d 7d2c2269 64223a22 67746c5f 35227d>}

My code is

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ImageView.image, 1.0);
NSString *mimeType = @"image/png";
GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:mimeType];
GTLQueryDrive *query=[GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:metadata uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
[_service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
if (error == nil) {
           NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }

}];
```

Comment: I don't know how to get the permission to access and upload the image

Answer (score 1):

In these two actions, I do not have permission to make changes.
following code in my project.

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:self.fromPath];
        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:fileHandle MIMEType:mimeType];
        GTLQueryDrive *uploadFileQuery = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:toFile
                                                                     uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
```