# Error: Upload file to google drive using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

Now I'm trying to upload file to Google Drive.
Code was built successfully, but my file didn't upload to Google Drive.

Here is my code.

```
-(void)uploadFileToGoogleDrive : (NSString*)fileName fileFullPath:(NSString*)filePath {

    GTLDriveFile *driveFile = [GTLDriveFile object];

    driveFile.mimeType = @"application/pdf";
    driveFile.originalFilename = filePath;
    driveFile.name = fileName;

    NSString *parentId = @"root";
    driveFile.parents = @[parentId];

    NSData *fileContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"application/pdf"];


    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:driveFile uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    [self.service executeQuery:query
             completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                 GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                 NSError *error) {
                 if (error == nil) {
                     NSLog(@"\nfile uploaded into google drive");
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"\nAn error occurred: %@", error);
                 }
             }];
}
```

Error message is like this:

```
Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=501 "(null)"
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [blog](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E501.html), error 501 occurs more likely if the client is not a Web browser - particularly if the Web server is old. In either case if the client has specified a valid request type, then the Web server is either responding incorrectly or simply needs to be upgraded.

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37358052/5832311), make sure that you have permission to make changes in these two actions:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:self.fromPath];
        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:fileHandle MIMEType:mimeType];
        GTLQueryDrive *uploadFileQuery = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:toFile
                                                                     uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
```

You can also check on this related threads:

- [not be able to upload a file to Google Drive](https://teratail.com/questions/34515)
- [Cannot upload/download files through google drive api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183663/cannot-upload-download-files-through-google-drive-api)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My file uploaded successfully. Thank you again. Can you help me one more? What is the MIMEType of recording file (.caf) ?

Comment: You can post another question regarding your issue. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed it. If I have another questions, I'll ask to you. Are you Ok?